# Installing R package from source using docker file

Tags: r, docker, dockerfile, r-package, install.packages

I am trying to install an r package from source using the dockerfile. Like seen here (using ggplot2 for simplicity)

```
FROM rocker/r-ver

COPY . /usr/local/src/myscripts
WORKDIR /usr/local/src/myscripts

RUN R -e 'install.packages("ggplot2_3.0.0.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")'

CMD ["Rscript", "run.R"]
```

Once I build the image I get this error

```
> install.packages("ggplot2_3.0.0.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
ERROR: dependencies ‘digest’, ‘gtable’, ‘lazyeval’, ‘plyr’, ‘reshape2’, 
‘rlang’, ‘scales’, ‘tibble’, ‘viridisLite’, ‘withr’ are not available for 
package ‘ggplot2’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/ggplot2’
Warning message:
In install.packages("ggplot2_3.0.0.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source") 
:>
> installation of package ‘ggplot2_3.0.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

The files included in the docker folder can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DW4FH.png)

Does anyone know what I need to add to the dockerfile to solve (if possible) this error?

Comment: Is there a specific reason to install packages from source?

Comment: Yes. I have an r package created by a coworker i want to include in a docker image. Do you have any suggestions on how I can approach this differently?

Comment: OK in that case you have full control over the list of dependencies so the approach you’ve taken in the other comment works. That said, you still don’t need to install a *source* package, your colleague can well compile it and pass the compiled package to you for installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you set `repos = NULL`, you will need to install all of the mentioned dependencies first — and *their* dependencies before that. You can do this manually but figuring out all dependencies is going to be a hassle, and is subject to change with every update.

It’s therefore probably better to use a local package manager. I have no personal experience with any of them but you can give [{miniCRAN}](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/miniCRAN/index.html) a try.

Comment: Added: "RUN install2.r digest gtable lazyeval plyr reshape2 rlang scales tibble viridisLite withr" prior to the installation of the ggplot for installing its dependencies and that seems to solve the problem!